# broken vertical scroll with overflow auto on mobile chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scrollbar, overflow

I am trying to create a mobile sidebar that has the following elements one under the other:

logo container -> ul list with menu items -> footer with social icons.
The logo container and the footer will be displayed above the ul list using the zIndex values.

Everything works as it should on the desktop browser but when I check it on the mobile chrome/safari is not working, however, on the brave browser, it works.

Both the logo container and the footer should be fixed and the list should allow scroll when there are many elements. I think I tried all the internet at this moment. Does anyone have any clue what should I do? Below is my CSS for this component.

```
  [`& .${classes.toolbar}`]: {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    display: 'block',
    width: '224px',
    backgroundColor:
      theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? 'white' : '#1F4B76',
    zIndex: 100,
  },

  [`& .${classes.scrollableList}`]: {
    marginTop: '182px',
    marginBottom: '74px',
    height: '100%',
    height: '-webkit-calc(100% - 252px)',
    height: 'calc(100% - 252px)',
    maxHeight: '70vh',
    maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 252px)',
    zIndex: 50,
    overflow: 'auto',
  },

  [`& .${classes.footer}`]: {
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: 0,
    display: 'block',
    width: '224px',
    backgroundColor:
      theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? 'white' : '#1F4B76',
    zIndex: 100,
  },
```

The actual behavior on the mobile chrome is as follows. Chrome allows me to scroll until some point after which I have to stop scrolling and if I try to scroll again it will render an extra scroll on the parent component and will use it to go to the end of the list. The same behavior happens when I try to scroll up. It's so complicated to test it out since I have to always deploy for each change and check if it works. Any idea would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more information? HTML and maybe a working example?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by setting height: auto, maxHeight: auto, overflow: auto.